# Codename One -proguard

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, codenameone, proguard

I downloaded the Codename One tutorial project, added some custom code with libraries but when building the project I get 'Compliance Check Failed' error. This error is cauesed by multiple Proguard warnings like:

1. there were # unresolved references to library class members.
2. there were # unresolved references to program class members.

These libraries are working fine just the proguard warnings create an error. I want to add '-dontwarn' option to the proguard config file but the problem is there is no such file. Any ideas how to correct this error? I'm using IntelliJ Idea. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build hint `android.proguardKeep` to add the additional parameters e.g.:

```
android.proguardKeep=-keep class com.mypackage.ProblemClass { *; }`
```

You can add the build hints in Codename One Settings. See the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html) for more.